# Java - how to get list with installed RPM packages

Tags: java, linux, rpm

I want to create JSF page which can display the installed RPM packages on the server on which the JSF page is running. How this can be done? How I can get this list with Java?

Best wishes

Answer (score 4):

I guess you'll have to shell out and use the rpm command.

Something like:

```
Process rpmProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rpm -qa");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rpmProc.getInputStream()));

String package;
while ((package = input.readLine()) != null) {
    // .. do something
}
```